# Por que eclipse no me crea una carpeta(folder) si no un package

Tags: eclipse, packages, java-build-path

Al instalar Hibernate en eclipse le di a una opcionde Build Path no recuerdo cual y todas las carpetas que tenían se convirtieron enpackages.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora cada vez que quiero crear una carpeta me sale en formato package.
Como puedo hacer que vuelva a como estaba antesjva

Comment: Parece que el proyecto tiene definida la carpeta raíz como origen del código. Si usas el botón derecho del ratón sobre ésta debería haber una opción para marcar/desmarcar la carpeta como "source folder", que debería ser "src"

Comment: He buscado lo que me comentas pero no lo encuentro por ningun lado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente: Configura el build path

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la pestaña *Source* seguramente tengas la carpeta raíz añadida, con lo que toda carpeta dentro se trata como un paquete de Java:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Elimina dicha carpeta (botón *Remove*) y añade (*Add Folder*) la carpeta `src`.

Eso debería configurar propiamente el proyecto.